# Qt5: How to read/write the file in local file system

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm new to Qt.In my app,I want to press a button and it will come out a QFileDialog to let me select the file in file system .So how to do that?

After that , here is my problem, I don't know which API in Qt works just like "open" in POSIX ? I think if I can open the file in the right way , this API will return me a file descriptor and I can read/write this file like open did in posix.

I read some documents and found some classes such as QFile QDataStream but I don't know if they are exactly what I want.

Comment: @alediaferia what you said is exactly what I want.Thank you for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are exactly what you are looking for.
In particular, you can use some of the static methods of [QFileDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) to get a reference to the file you want to open, like:

```
static QString  getOpenFileName(QWidget * parent = 0, const QString & caption = QString(), const QString & dir = QString(), const QString & filter = QString(), QString * selectedFilter = 0, Options options = 0)
```

and then use a [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) and [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) or [QTextStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) to read the contents.

You'd use QDataStream for reading binary data most of the times, like follows:

```
QFile f(fileName);
if (f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QDataStream stream(&f);
    int data;
    stream >> data;
}
```

Otherwise you can read plain text with QTextStream as follows:

```
QTextStream stream(&f);
QString line;
do {
    line = stream.readLine();
    /* do something with the line */
} while (!line.isNull());
```

Qt docs are pretty complete, you just have to take your time and read them. There's also plenty of [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html).

Answer (score 0):

Only Reading:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open file"), "", tr("all Files ()"));

QFile file(fileName);

if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
QByteArray arr = file.readAll();
file.close();
}
```

Only Writing:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open file"), "", tr("all Files ()"));

QFile file(fileName);

if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
file.write(QBtyeArray("Heelo World"));
file.close();
}
```

Read and Write:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open file"), "", tr("all Files ()"));

QFile file(fileName);

if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
QByteArray arr = file.readAll();
arr += " From Earth";
file.write(arr);
file.close();
}
```

if you use QDatastream you do not need resolve how many part you have written before,follow Below Code and I always use this method;

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDatastream out(&buffer);

out << QString("Hello World QString");
out << QByteArray("Hello World QByteArray");
out << int(55);

buffer.close();

QFile file(fileName);
if(file.open(QIIDevice::WriteOnly)){

file.write(buffer.data());
file.close();
}
```

and reading this file

```
QFile file(fileName);
if(file.open(QIIDevice::WriteOnly)){

QDatastream in(&file);

QString str;
QByteArray arr;
int integer;

in >> str;
in >> arr;
in >> integer;

file.close();

}
```

str is "Hello World QString";

arr is "Hello World QByteArray";

integer is 55;

QDataStream is adding extra bytes to file for your parts and if you read it with QDataStream, QDataStream solve how many parts and each part bytes instead of you.